# cpplint misbehaving in docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, cpplint

I'm trying to run cpplint.py inside a Docker container.

Here's the Dockerfile which I use to make an image lint:latest :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# update and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y -qq install software-properties-common \
    && apt-get -y -qq install python3.7 \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# install our linter
COPY cpplint.py /usr/sbin
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/cpplint.py

# install a test file
COPY Types.h .
```

I run the container like this:

```
$ docker run -it --rm lint:latest bash
root@17a20248ee33:/# cpplint.py Types.h
root@17a20248ee33:/# echo $?
1
```

Which shows cpplint.py returning an error code.

Note that running `cpplint.py --help` displays the help screen as normal. It's long so I'm not going to list it here.

Running the same command outside of a container works fine:

```
$ ./cpplint.py Types.h
Types.h:0:  No #ifndef header guard found, suggested CPP variable is: _LINT_TYPES_H_  [build/header_guard] [5]
Done processing Types.h
Total errors found: 1
```

According to [Docker's run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) both STDOUT and STDERR are attached to the terminal by default. I understand that cpplint writes errors to STDERR, but don't think that's why I don't see the same output when run within a container. I've tried the `2>&1` manoeuvre to force STDERR onto STDOUT and got the same results.

Any ideas why I don't see output from cpplint.py when I run it in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the container try installing `cpplint.py` using `pip3`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# update and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y -qq install software-properties-common \
    && apt-get -y -qq install python3.7 python3-pip \
    && pip3 install cpplint

# install a test file
COPY Types.h .
```

Comment: Thanks - that helped a bit `root@0d6c341a408f:/# cpplint ./Types.h
Done processing ./Types.h` but it's not producing the error messages when run from outside a container.

Comment: Which cpplint version do you use outside of container? Where did you get it from? The pip version is comming from a fork - https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint. Have you modified cpplint? Which python version do you use on the host?

Comment: cpplint.py supports per-directory configurations specified in CPPLINT.cfg so if you have such config on the host copy it in the container

Comment: I discovered that removing the `#pragma once` from the beginning of `Types.h` caused the version installed using Vasil's method to work.`# cpplint --version
Cpplint fork (https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint)
cpplint 1.4.4
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]`

Comment: the version I downloaded from GitHub doesn't even have `--version` as a valid flag, so it's clearly different to the one I pipped.

Comment: I'm not sure about the pragma once but if you find it problematic consider reporting this upstream. There is one issue about it but without any answers https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/issues/65

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that, but it just got weirder.  If I make a file that begins with `#pragma once` from inside the container the linter behaves normally.

Comment: I think what's happened is that the version in the container now recognizes `#pragma once` as an include guard which was the only style error in the file. In other words, it's working :-) I'll try it with a few other files.

Comment: confirming that cpplint treats `#pragma once` as an include guard. The other files I just tried it caused the linter to behave as I'd expect. Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.